# Spring Integration with DSL: Can File Outbound Channel Adapter create file after say 10 mins of interval

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a requirement where my application should read messages from MQ and write using file outbound channel adapter. I want each of my output file should contain messages of every 10 mins of interval. Is there any default implementation exist, or any pointers to do so.

```
    public @Bean IntegrationFlow defaultJmsFlow()
{
    return IntegrationFlows.from(

            //read JMS topic
            Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.connectionFactory).destination(this.config.getInputQueueName()).errorChannel(errorChannel()).configureListenerContainer(c ->
            {
                final DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = c.get();
                container.setSessionTransacted(true);
                container.setMaxMessagesPerTask(-1);

            }).get())

            .channel(messageProcessingChannel()).get();
}

public @Bean MessageChannel messageProcessingChannel()
{
    return MessageChannels.queue().get();
}

public @Bean IntegrationFlow messageProcessingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageProcessingChannel())

            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(config.getWorkingDir()))
                    .fileNameGenerator(fileNameGenerator())
                    .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND).appendNewLine(true))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you could use something like a `QueueChannel` with the `poller` on the endpoint for the `FileWritingMessageHandler` with the `fixedDelay` for those 10 mins. However you should keep in mind that messages are going to be stored in the memory before poller does its work. So, once a crash of your application, the messages are lost.

On the other hand you can use a `JmsDestinationPollingSource` with similar `poller` configuration. This way, however, you need to configure it with the `maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)` to let it to pull as much messages from the MQ as possible during single polling task - once in 10 mins.

Another variant is possible with an `aggregator` and its `groupTimeout` option. This way you won't have an output message from the aggregator until 10 mins interval passes. However again: the store is in memory by default. I wouldn't introduce one more persistence storage just to satisfy a periodic requirement when we already have an MQ and we really can poll exactly that. Therefore I would go a `JmsDestinationPollingSource` variant.

**UPDATE**

> Can you help me with how to set fixed delay in file outbound adapter.

Since you deal with the `QueueChannel`, you need to configure for the "fixed delay" a `PollingConsumer` endpoint. This one really belongs to the subscriber of that channel. Indeed it is a `.handle(Files.outboundAdapter)` part. Only what you are missing that `Poller` is an option of the endpoint, not a `MessageHandler`. Consider to use an overloaded `handle()`variant:

```
.handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(config.getWorkingDir()))
                .fileNameGenerator(fileNameGenerator())
                .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND).appendNewLine(true),
       e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10000)))
```

> Or a sample example for `JMSDestinationPollingSource`

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory())
                        .destination("jmsInbound"),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10000)))
                .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
                .channel(jmsOutboundInboundReplyChannel())
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: I'm going with the first approach. Also I have updated question with example. Can you help me with how to set fixed delay in file outbound adapter. Or a sample example for `JMSDestinationPollingSource`

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.